# Mock services in spring application when runing on jetty

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mocking, jetty, mockito

I want to run my spring web application on jetty with mocking services, because my services call a distant REST services which are not yet available.

I use JUnit classes to test my controllers, it works very well using MockMvc, Mockito and ReflectionTestUtils.setField(..,..,..) to inject my mock behavior.

But now I want to see my JSPs interacting and validate the GUI, is there a way to mock my services when running on jetty.

This is my jetty class :

```
public final class MobileUITestServer {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MobileUITestServer.class);
  private static Server server;

  /**
   * Constructeur.
   */
  private MobileUITestServer() {}

  /**
   * Launch server.
   *
   * @param args arguments
   * @throws Exception error
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("PMD.SignatureDeclareThrowsException")
  public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    start(1234);

    LOG.info("Joining this thread with server thread...");
    server.join();
  }

  /**
   * Start Mobile UI server.
   *
   * @param port port
   * @throws Exception error
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("PMD.SignatureDeclareThrowsException")
  public static void start(int port) throws Exception {
    LOG.info("Starting server on port {}", port);
    server = new Server(port);

    WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
    webapp.setContextPath("/");
    webapp.setDescriptor("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml");
    webapp.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp");

    server.setHandler(webapp);

    server.start();
    LOG.info("Server started");
  }

  /**
   * Stop this server.
   *
   * @throws Exception error
   */
  @SuppressWarnings({"PMD.AvoidThrowingRawExceptionTypes", "PMD.SignatureDeclareThrowsException"})
  public static void stop() throws Exception {
    if(server == null || !server.isRunning()) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Server is not running...");
    }

    LOG.info("Stopping server");
    server.stop();

    LOG.info("Server stopped");
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the nature of your web services? Read Only/CRUD? JSON/XML?

Comment: only JSON, and there are CRUDs and other complex services

Answer (score 0):

I assume (I do not know what version of Spring you use, which modules and the context configuration) you have some kind of service written using SpringData, JPA, Hibernate so the idea could be to use an embedded database such as H2 providing some mock data and the same sql schema you have already written. You just have to substitute the DataSource object.

If you want to write a more versatile solution you could use Spring's profiles in order to define the context objects w.r.t. the environment you want to run the webapp into (i.e. test, development, production and so on).

For instance:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.contrastofbeauty.mydomain"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<context:annotation-config/>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.contrastofbeauty.myrepository" entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"
                  transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>
```

Here I defined the dataSource as H2 database, the schema to be loaded and the data.

```
 <beans profile="dev">
    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql"/>
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:dev-data.sql"/>
    </jdbc:embedded-database>
</beans>
```

[Here an example](https://github.com/blackat/spring-jpa) of a test using SpringData, SpringTest and Spring's profiles.

I hope it helps.

Latest thing: why not to use Maven to manage the project and Maven Jetty plugin? you can start your web application inside you IDE (Eclipse, Intellij, etc) for me it is easier but I do not know your requirements.